# Easier way to refer to embedded PDFs?

Tags: vba, pdf, embed, ms-word

I'm working on a word doc with a bunch of embedded PDFs, and I need to be able to activate them with VBA macros. So here's what I've been doing:

```
ThisDocument.InlineShapes(appropriate_number).OLEFormat.Activate
```

But the problem is that having to refer to each pdf by some arbitrary index number means that if I insert another embedded PDF between a couple pre-existing ones, then all of my code could break (since the index numbers to refer to certain embedded pdfs would shift).

Is there a more efficient way to refer to embedded PDFs in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `AlternativeText`property to refer to the Inline Shapes. If the PDFs are being embedded programatically, capture the filename of each pdf and assign the filename to `AlternativeText`.

```
 NewShapeIndex = ActiveDocument.InlineShapes.Count + 1
 'Code to embed shape and capture filename of PDF
 ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(NewShapeIndex).AlternativeText = CapturedFilename
```

(If the PDFs are being embedded manually, right-click on the embedded PDF icon, choose Format Object, and input the file name into the box on the Alt Text tab for each file.)

Then use the `InlineShapes` collection to launch a file based on the file name:

```
Public Sub PDFindex(PDFname As String)

Dim Myshape As InlineShape
Dim IndexCount As Integer
IndexCount = 1

For Each Myshape In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes

    If Myshape.AlternativeText = PDFname Then
        ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(IndexCount).OLEFormat.Activate
    End If
    IndexCount = IndexCount + 1

Next

End Sub
```

In this way, as long as you know the names of your files, you can launch any file with

```
 PDFindex filename
```